# ASP.NET SMTP Failover solutions

Tags: asp.net, smtp, msmq, rabbitmq

My knowledge and experience of this is limited, so not sure if I've considered everything and would appreciate some advice.

Current scenario: one Exchange server, one database server, multiple load balanced webservers, all sending confirmation and alert emails on a regular basis.  This exchange server is used extensively across the business which is causing a high load which the exchange server can't handle.  At one point the server went down for an extended length of time, leading to emails not reaching their destination and with no logging of email attempts to determine what emails failed, so that they can be manually sent at a later date.  Additionally, the website waits for the SMTP response so there's a delay in the web page loading.

Plan: A second SMTP server is to be introduced to reduce the load on the original server, along with implementing some improvements to the website to reduce it's resource hogging and improve logging of all email attempts (just header info), with SMTP response status.

Possible Solutions:

1. Change the website's email method to log, then attempt SMTP via one or other server, record the smtp response.  Pros: Quicker to develop, Cons: No asynchronous processing of email queue.
2. Log email headers, then use MSMQ or RabbitMQ to send email request to a queue, and have a listener service that handles the process of actually sending the email to the Exchange server.   Additionally if it continues to fail to reach the SMTP servers, leave it in the queue and retry again at a later time.  Pros: Can re-use the infrastructure and experience to use MQ in future feature requirements like user requests to download data, a la Facebook. Cons: Time to learn how to do it, and actually develop when faced with a deadline.
3. Log email to db, then send to a local pickup folder which relays to the Exchange server, but I think this has no failover support, or method for updating the status in the email log, so while it seems quick to set up, doesn't really meet all of the requirements as far as I can see.

What I'm tempted to do is do is develop in two phases, initially just the first solution then develop the MSMQ/RabbitMQ functionality to make it asynchronous at a later date, but thought I'd ask for opinions to see if I'm overlooking something.

Comment: Is there a requirement for you to use Exchange for **all** email? If not, you can/should look into external services that have the ability to queue and do failover for your messaging needs. I can imagine the load your servers get if they do "everything" (spam/anti-x/etc.). If possible, consider outsourcing pieces that you can.....

Comment: That would be a good solution ordinarily, but unfortunately this is for a client, and they keep their emails in-house, through their own servers, rather than outsourcing.

Comment: How about figuring out which emails can just use IIS SMTP server vs. Exchange - e.g. web site emails, transactional emails, etc. - each of your web servers can potentially be in a pool of SMTP servers. Am still of the mindset to figure out which **must** use Exchange vs. some other MTA....

Comment: Is there a reason why the website waits for SMTP responses? I mean, if you could guarantee that an email will eventually get sent (by using durable queues etc.), would you still need to wait for a response?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [NServiceBus](http://nservicebus.com/).

Specifically, there's some very new email functionality. A satellite has been created that gives you the benefits of the retries that come with NServiceBus to make your email sending more robust.

You get a separate queue without requiring a new endpoint or configuring any message mappings. This way every endpoint has this capability built in and the only config needed is a SmtpClient config section.

The API for this feature is `Bus.SendEmail(new MailMessage)`. They’re using the `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` as the abstraction for sending emails.

The code is currently in their [develop branch](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/tree/develop/src/Notifications). A sample demonstrating all this can be found [here](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/commit/0bb5516484a50b2629548605dd639736beca4e96).

For more details see [here](http://andreasohlund.net/2012/06/07/sending-emails-using-nservicebus/)